# Angular Http Caching and Race Conditions

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to figure out how to best solve a race condition in my app in the simplest way possible.

I have a route with two resolvers. The resolvers are:

`GetBooksResolver`

`GetAuthorsResolver`

Now, both Authors and Books have a type `Genre` that needs to be merged in.

Thus in both of the resolvers, you have a forkJoin:

```
// GetBooksResolver:
forkJoin(this.http.get('api/genres'), this.http.get('api/books'))
    .pipe(map(data => //merge datasets));

//GetAuthorsResolver
forkJoin(this.http.get('api/genres'), this.http.get('api/authors'))
    .pipe(map(data => //merge datasets));
```

I have a simple HTTP caching service that does correctly prevent the HTTP requests from firing again, **but the initial race condition is still there**.

As a result, you see **two different `api/genre` calls**

Any way to set up a caching interceptor so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: Could you set up another method that returns an observable from `this.http.get('api/genres').publishReplay(1).refCount()`?  Reference [here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/caching-with-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2.0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments you can create a method that will call the service return a replay `Observable` like this:

```
public getGenres(): Observable<Genre> {
  return this.httpClient.get('api/genres').pipe(
    shareReplay(1)
  );
}
```

Then you call this method to get the replay `Observable` and use it in both forkJoin methods:

```
const genres$ = this.getGenres();
// GetBooksResolver:
forkJoin(genres$, this.http.get('api/books'))
    .pipe(map(data => //merge datasets));

//GetAuthorsResolver
forkJoin(genres$, this.http.get('api/authors'))
    .pipe(map(data => //merge datasets));
```

I have also created a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knhbji?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) sample so you can see it in action.